# using fpdf and phpmailer in foreach loop to send pdfs to multiple addresses

Tags: php, foreach, phpmailer, fpdf

i have a checkbox form with a list of jobs that posts to pdf.php. What i am looking to do is have fpdf generate a pdf and mail it using phpmailer.

Each checkbox has a different email associated with it. So for every box checked, the file will generate a pdf of that particular job and send it to the corresponding email address

At the minute i can only get the first email to send,without the pdf attached, nothing is generated for the rest.
Here is an example of the form:

```
<tr><td>123</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value= "123"></td></tr>
<tr><td>456</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value= "456"></td></tr>
<tr><td>789</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value= "789"></td></tr>
```

and a simplified version of the pdf generation and email :

```
require('msqliconnect.php');
require('fpdf.php');
require("PHPMailer.php");

if (isset($_POST['job'])) {
    foreach($_POST['job'] as $id) {

    //sql query to get more info about job
    $sql ="select * from jobs where job = $id";
    $queryresult = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryresult,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            $pdf = new FPDF(); 
            $pdf->AddPage(); 

            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16); 
            $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $id, 0, 1, 'C'); 
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', NULL, 12); 
            $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $row['amount'], 1, 1, 'L'); 
            $pdf->Output('Job#'. $id .'.pdf','F');

            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP(); 
            //and so on to generate the email
            $mail->AddAttachment('Job#'. $id .'.pdf');
            if(!$mail->Send()) {
               echo 'Message was not sent.';
               echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                echo '<body>Message has been sent.</body>';
            } 

            unlink('Job#'. $id .'.pdf');

        }
    } 
}
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this.

Comment: I updated your question - I've moved the require to the top of the page. May of caused an issue

Comment: I've noticed your unlink has the wrong filename

Comment: Is the folder which the pdfs are being generated  writable?

Comment: yes permissions are correct for it.

Comment: Try sticking some echos in your foreach and while loops - even a print_r to check everything is posted - you might be able to pinpoint where its going wrong

Comment: Base your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps), then you only need to worry about PDF generation.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used phpmailer for a while.... but I think this should attach a file:

```
$mail->AddAttachment('job'. $id .'.pdf');
```

Oh... Check that the folder which the pdfs are being generated is writable!

Comment: ah yeah, that part is in the fuller version, will update the question with it

Comment: apologies that is a typo, not in the full code i trying.

Comment: just rechecked the full code and there was a typo in the phpmailer section. It is now attached the pdf to the email, but still only for the first of the selected jobs. one problem down.

Answer (score 0):

By read your code
the problem just from `$pdf->Output('Job#'. $id .'.pdf','F');`
For more information about `Output()`, please read from the documentation http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm

The solution is, if you are using option `'F'` for your output, then you should put the full path of directory of where the pdf is saved.
 And you could write like this
`$filename='your_full_path_directory_of_pdf_saved/Job_'.$id.'.pdf';
 $pdf->Output($filename,'F');`

(I change your `"#"` character into `"_"` character because `"#"` in the file name could be bad practice)

make sure you also change your
`$mail->AddAttachment('Job#'. $id .'.pdf');` 
into
`$mail->AddAttachment($filename');` 
And
`unlink('Job#'. $id .'.pdf');`
into
`unlink($filename);`
CMIIW